# Need suggestion on upload method

Tags: android, file-upload

Created an application that uploads pictures from camera or gallery via php file. I need to upload it from all sorts of networks to do that I would have to port forward my external address and that isn't safe. I could go with DMZ but ain't safe also. Open ports  to other world ain't good. How could I upload image to my server without having to port forward?

Comment: I have no idea what your server looks like, but if you use HTTPS then 443 is open.  (assuming it's open for the rest of the world). Then again, I do not know what your infrastructure looks like and how you want to communicate with your server.

Comment: Currently for testing I am using raspberry. I am searching for ideas that are more secure to upload image. Right now I have to do this: private String UploadUrl = "http://myIP:3307/imageuploadapp/uploadinfo.php";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to use firebase which is more safer